# Isotope Masonry with multiple widths columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, plugins

I'm trying to do this layout using which has 3 different widths using masonry:

[image]

The problem is that the last element doesn't seem to work so this is what I get:

[image]

This is my code:

```
$( function() {

  $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    masonry: {
      columnWidth: 394
    }
  });

});


#main{
    width: 1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    .isotope{
        max-width: 1250px;
        .item {
        float: left;
        width: 394px;
            &.width2 { 
                width: 835px;
            }
            &.width3 { 
                width: 367px; 
            }
        }
    }
}
    <div id="main">
        <div class="isotope">
            <div class="item"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/home-1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/home-2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/home-3.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item width2"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/home-4.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item width3"><img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/img/home-5.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: I'm using Less, why?

Comment: less doesn't work in browser, unless you have compiled it to css.

Comment: Yeah it's compiled... I just put the uncompiled version here. Didn't see a problem about doing it

Answer (score 0):

1.jpg is the wider image and 2.jgp is small onces

```html
   <div id="main">
        <div class="isotope">
            <div class="item"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item width2"><img src="1.jpg"></div>
            <div class="item width3"><img src="2.jpg"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Hey I just split the class items in your code and it worked.

```css
<style>
#main{
    width: 1250px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#main  
.isotope{
        max-width: 1250px;
}
.item {
        float: left;
        width: 394px;
}
.width2 { 
         width: 835px;
}
.width3 { 
        width: 367px; 
}
</style>
```